# error genexus. soap (wsdl) (xmlwrite)

Tags: soap, genexus, wsdl

me sale el siguiente error si alguien me puede ayudar

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/CharToByteConverter
        at com.genexus.xml.XMLWriter.writeStartDocument(Unknown Source)
        at Sdtwsaa.logincms(Sdtwsaa.java:61)
        at afip.privateExecute(afip.java:422)
        at afip.execute_int(afip.java:38)
        at afip.execute(afip.java:30)
        at uworkpanel1.e12V012(uworkpanel1.java:206)
        at uworkpanel1.actionEventDispatch(uworkpanel1.java:273)
        at com.genexus.ui.GXWorkpanel$runEvent.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.CharToByteConverter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: Joaquin, que versión/upgrade de GX estás usando? Además precisaría conocer que versión de Tomcat y jdk tienes. 

Tengo entendido que el método que da error se dejó de soportar en Tomcat 8, por eso precisaría conocer si efectivamente se trata de eso o de otra cosa. 

Gracias.